# Performance of compiled functions (Project Euler No14)

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, project-euler

I was playing around with the project euler [problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14).

The solution I came up with is listed below as `cf1`. The solution works fine but I get the compiler warning:

```
Compile::cset: Variable max of type _Integer encountered in assignment of type _Real.
```

I don't get this message at all since the only assignment of max is `max=l` while `Head@l == Integer`. This error can be fixed by substituting with `max=Round[l]`. Any ideas?

```
cf1 = Compile[{}, Module[{l, max = 0, maxN = 0},
  Do[
   l = Length[NestWhileList[If[EvenQ[#], #~Quotient~2, 3 # + 1] &, n, # != 1 &]];
   If[l > max, max = l; maxN = n];
   , {n, 1, 10^4}];
   {max, maxN}
  ]];
cf1[] // Timing

{6.349241, {262, 6171}}
```

I also found a solution with much better performance listed below as `cf2`. Is it just that `NestWhileList` doesn't compile very good or is there another reason why this solution is so much faster?

```
cf2 = Compile[{}, Module[{n1, l, max = 0, maxN = 0},
  Do[
   n1 = n;
   l = 1;
   While[n1 != 1, n1 = If[EvenQ[n1], n1~Quotient~2, 3 n1 + 1]; l++];
   If[l > max, max = l; maxN = n];
   , {n, 1, 10^4}];
   {max, maxN}
  ]];
cf2[] // Timing

{0.374402, {262, 6171}}
```

Comment: I have no familiarity with `Compile` but this was my solution which I thought was intuitive (warning: it's painfully slow): `Clear[euler14];
euler14[n_?EvenQ] := n/2;
euler14[n_?OddQ] := 3 n + 1;
MaximalBy[{#, Length@NestWhileList[euler14, #, # != 1 &]} & /@ Range[1, 10^4], Last] // Timing (* {2.683217, {{6171, 262}}} *)`. I was surprised that the `#`'s of the `NestWhileList` and one used to map to the list of number (from 1 to 10^4) play nice with each other.

Comment: @seismatica Thanks for sharing! It's a really nice problem which can be approached form many different angles. Check out this fast, uncompiled solution based on recursion.(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33400/4539)

Comment: Thank you! There's also another fast(er) [solution](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Collection_of_Computer_Programs_on_Project_Euler#Problem_14) (using recursion?) that I found from googling. MMA is my first programming language so I'm not used to recursive programming, and `Do` loops really make me go into a tailspin!

Comment: Related: [(33396)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33396/improve-the-performance-of-solutions-to-project-euler-14)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fix the error by setting `max = 0.` (Note the `.`).

But this doesn't really `Compile` completely and you can check that by inspecting the 6th `Part` of the compiled function:

```
FreeQ[cf1[[6]], _Function, {0, Infinity}]

False
```

Whenever your compiled function has a `Function` definition in `Part` 6, your function did not compile properly. On the other hand, inspecting `cf2` we see:

```
FreeQ[cf2[[6]], _Function, {0, Infinity}]
```

> True

Also,

```
MatchQ[cf2[[6]], {{__Integer} ..}]
```

> True

This tells us that not only did the function `Compile` correctly, there's no call to `MainEvaluate`, so the performance will be top notch as you noticed. Finally, you can get better performance if you have a `C` compiler by adding the `Option`: `CompilationTarget -> "C"`

```
cf3 = Compile[{}, 
  Module[{n1, l, max = 0, maxN = 0}, 
   Do[n1 = n; l = 1; 
    While[n1 != 1, n1 = If[EvenQ[n1], n1~Quotient~2, 3 n1 + 1]; l++]; 
    If[l > max, max = l; maxN = n];, {n, 1, 10^4}]; {max, maxN}],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

**Timings**

```
cf1[] // Timing
cf2[] // Timing
cf3[] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.578125, {262., 6171.}}
> {0.093750, {262, 6171}}
> {0.031250, {262, 6171}}
> ```