# Plotting recursive from a for loop

Tags: recursion, list-manipulation, plotting

our assignment is that we have make a plot for the possition of 1's 
From the recursive function
if `a[n-1]` is even then `a[n]=a[n-1]/2` 
and if `a[n-1]` is odd then `a[n]=3*a[n-1]+1`
where we have to find at which possition the first 1 occures for `10000<=a[n]<=2`.

So for this we have to do a for loop with if statment

```
list = {};

b[n_] := b[n] = If[EvenQ[b[n - 1]], b[n - 1]/2, 3*b[n - 1] + 1];

For[b[1] = 10000, b[1] =2, b[1]--, 

  AppendTo[list, Min [Position[Table[b[n], {n, 1, 30}], 1]]]];

list

ListPlot[list]
```

The problem we get is that every outprint will be for `b[1]=10000` that is `30`. And this is not what we were expecting. We know that the problem is that we can not use `Clear[b]` in a good way inside the loop, but is there any other way that this problem can be solved. ? For this the lector has adviced us to use `ListPlot`.

Comment: just do `b[n_] := If .. ` so you dont need to clear `b` each time you change `b[1]`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33396/1871 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56198/1871

Comment: Really? Someone is teaching you Mathematica using `For` loops and `AppendTo`? That's just depressing. See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/8

Comment: Hopefully the use of `For` and `AppendTo` is the student's interpretation of the task (and not the preferred approach).

Comment: should have put "in principle" in my first comment.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method using recursion with memoization. The trick is to create a recursive function which returns the **length** of the chain to 1, rather than just the next value. So for example when starting with 10000 the next value you get is 5000 and you have already memoized that it is 29 steps from 5000 to 1, so it must be 1+29 = 30 from 10000 to 1.

This is quite a bit faster - the results for 1 to 10000 are obtained in a fraction of a second.

```
ClearAll[steps]

mem : steps[x_?EvenQ] := mem = 1 + steps[x/2];
mem : steps[x_] := mem = 1 + steps[3 x + 1];
steps[1] = 1;

steps /@ Range[10]
(* {1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9, 17, 4, 20, 7} *)

ListPlot[steps /@ Range[10000]]
```

[image]

Comment: Simon -- this is very clever!

Comment: @SimonWoods very instructive, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The subtlety here is that the recursion is memoized, so you cannot just change the value of `b[1]` and run the recursion again (and if you remove the memoization, it runs impossibly slowly). One approach is to clear the stored `b[ ]` values inside the loop and redefine the recursion each pass. Here it is for the first few terms:

```
startVals = Range[2, 10]; 
thisB = ConstantArray[0, Length[startVals]];
Do[Clear[b]; 
 b[n_] := b[n] = If[EvenQ[b[n - 1]], b[n - 1]/2, 3*b[n - 1] + 1]; 
 b[1] = startVals[[j]]; allB = b[#] & /@ Range[1000];
 thisB[[j]] = Min[Position[allB, 1]];, {j, 1, Length[startVals]}];
thisB

{2, 8, 3, 6, 9, 17, 4, 20, 7}
```

This can also be done without clearing the recursion definition each time by defining the recursion to be a function of two variables: the recursive variable and the starting value. For example:

```
b[m_, n_] := b[m, n] = If[EvenQ[b[m, n - 1]], b[m, n - 1]/2, 3*b[m, n - 1] + 1];
startVals = Range[2, 10];
Do[b[j, 1] = j, {j, 1, Length[startVals]}];
Table[allB = b[j, #] & /@ Range[1000]; 
      Min[Position[allB, 1]], {j, 2, Length[startVals]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f[u_] := Boole[EvenQ@u] u/2 + Boole[OddQ@u] (3 u + 1)
g[u_] := Last@NestWhile[{f@#[[1]], #[[2]] + 1} &, {u, 1}, First@# != 1 &]
res = {#, g[#]} & /@ Range[2, 10000];
```

Visualizing:

```
ListPlot[res, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a[1]", "a[n]=1"}, 
 BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

Or testing:

```
g[#] & /@ Range[10]
```

yields:

```
(*{1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9, 17, 4, 20, 7}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems not a terribly good use of recursion..if you need all the values you may as well just march it out:

```
 p[i0_] :=
   First@NestWhile[
      {#[[1]] + 1, If[EvenQ[ Last@# ], Last@#/2 , 3 Last@# + 1 ]} & ,
         {1, i0}, Last@# != 1 &]
 p /@ Range[10]
```

> {1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9, 17, 4, 20, 7}

```
 p /@ Range[2, 10000] // Timing // First
```

> 3.447622